# Get css styles from html content with regex

Tags: php, regex

I have got working regex

`$this->html`  - HTML data

```
$cssPattern = '/<link rel="stylesheet".*?href="(.+?)"\\s*?\/?>/si';
preg_match_all("{$cssPattern}", $this->html, $matches);
```

These regex work if rel="stylesheet" is before href but as I mention there is situations where it is after href and in these situation these regex do not work. Is it possible to make / check if rel="stylesheet" is before href or after href

Answer (score 0):

This RegEx should give you the url of the stylesheet, could be prettier but regex just isn't good for parsing html...

```
<link.*(?:rel="stylesheet".*|href="(.*)".*){2}.*\/>
```

Comment: I have made final line : $cssPattern = '/<link.*(?:rel="stylesheet".*|href="(.*)".*){2}.*\/>/si'; and it is not working :(

Comment: Hm strange, it works here: https://regex101.com/r/aD3tS7/1
Edit: Maybe you need to remove the **s** at the end